# How to remove a class from a clone only with Draggable and Droppable jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm currently trying to remove a class from a nested div inside of a li that is draggable.  The options that I'm trying are removing the class from the original li as well.  Would anyone have any insight?

**jQuery**

```
        $(function () {
            $(".drag li").each(function () {
                $(this).draggable({
                    cursor: "move",
                    revert: "invalid",
                    helper: "clone"                        
                });
            });     
        //Droppable function
        $(".droppable").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this).addClass("form-btn-wide");
                $("#test .elementHidden").removeClass("elementHidden");
            }

            //Sorting function
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            },
            over: function () {
                removeIntent = false;
            }, //Remove function
            out: function () {
                removeIntent = true;
            },
            beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                if (removeIntent == true) {
                    ui.item.remove();
                }
            }

            })         
        });
```

You can see the $("#test .elementHidden").removeClass("elementHidden"); is what I've tried, but to no avail.

Here's the example that I'm trying to remove the '.elementHidden' class from:

```
<ol id="twocol" class= "drag">
 <li id="test" class="btn form-btn draggable"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-header"></i> Header</span>
 <div class="elementHidden"><input type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel"></div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the issue is that when you run `.clone()`, it also clones all the attributes, including the `id`. Hence you then have 2 ekements with the same id and the selector may have an issue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a more complete example may help get an answer faster.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gyy2kqqz/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".drag li").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
  });
  //Droppable function
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var targetCount = $(this).find("[id*='clone']").length;
        var $dropElemClone = ui.draggable.clone();
        $dropElemClone
          .attr("id", dropId + "-clone-" + (targetCount + 1))
          .appendTo(this)
          .addClass("form-btn-wide")
          .find(".elementHidden")
          .removeClass("elementHidden");
      }
      //Sorting function
  }).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    },
    over: function() {
      removeIntent = false;
    }, //Remove function
    out: function() {
      removeIntent = true;
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
      if (removeIntent == true) {
        ui.item.remove();
      }
    }
  })
});
```

You will not need to use `.each()`; just use the proper selector and `.draggable()` will be applied to all elements in the selector.

Using clone is a double edged sword sometimes. You can clone an element fast, but you clone all of it. So before you append it back, you may want to ensure it has a unique `id` attribute.

It's often good practice to store your clone to a variable. This makes it's easier to work with later.

Lastly, to remove the class, we need to first select that element that has that class. Using `.find()` is the easiest way to do this. We expect it to be an element of this clone,we find it, and can then remove the class.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!  I do really appreciate you taking the time to explain it all, that helps me a ton.